# Mocking Tomee server properties

Tags: java, unit-testing, server, apache-tomee

I have written code so that `EntityManagerFactory` properties can be changed without restarting the server.
I tested it using RESTful jersey services.

Should I be writing junit tests to test this. I haven't written any thinking that since server has to be running to pick up modified properties file.

If it can be done i am not sure how to mock a server.
I would  appreciate your comments.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think a good start for light EE/TomEE tests is the ApplicationComposer, it allows to define a light embedded deployment. An alternative is to use tomee embedded which is not as light as ApplicationComposer but provides a full tomee with all features

http://tomee.apache.org/ng/developer/testing/index.html describes main ways to test your code in TomEE without mocking as much as possible (which would likely mean you don't test anymore your runtime).

Comment: you are right. I ended up using Arquillian for running the tests later. but I found that using System.setProperty() also seems to work for adding in environment variables in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should test every branch of code you write :) But think small at first, how can you test "one unit" of code, without injecting actual dependencies? If you're trying to mock out an entire server, you're no long unit testing, you're integration testing (which IS important, but not yet). If your code cannot be, or is too complicated, to be tested as a unit, you should redesign it to so!

Comment: I am trying to add in tests. I had a question about basic java. If we create an object using properties file, then I would assume that if I want to change a few properties I must recreate the variable.

please correct me if I am wrong in thinking like that.